# Calculate the average distance over all pairs of nodes in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

How can one calculate the average distance on a graph with 5 nodes?
Is there a simple way to find the average?
Can some one share some examples?

Thanks

Comment: What's the configuration of the graph?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very vague.

If you have a graph on 5 nodes then you can probably calculate the distances between all the pairs of vertices manually and then divide the result by 10

If you happen to have a large graph you can construct the all pair distance matrix (using for example [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) algorithm) and then sum all the entries of the matrix and divide by the number of all pairs of vertices.

Additionally, if you happen to know the [Wiener](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WienerIndex.html) index of your graph you just divide the index by $n(n-1)$ where $n$ is the number of vertices of your graph.